# Fetching the Last inner Message from C# exception Object Using Recursive Methods

Tags: c#, recursion

I want to fetch the *last inner* `exception` message using *recursive call*
The requirement here is using recursive function. 
I am trying to do it, but I think there is some *little issue*.
Here is My code

```
    public static string GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        string message ="";

        if (ex != null)
        {            
            if (ex.InnerException == null)
            {
                message  = "";
            }
            else
            {
              message = GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException);
            }
        }

        return message; 
    }
```

I constantly get *empty string* when I expect some message be returned if `ex != null`

Comment: do you want to get the last message from the inner exception?

Comment: just use `ex.GetBaseException().Message` or `ex.GetBaseException().ToString`. No need for your own recursive method.

Comment: You always return an empty string.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes this is the issue i am getting.

Comment: @lordvlad30 Yes I know I can use `GetBaseExceptionMethod` , but my lead has asked me to do using recursive method. Maybe he wants me to build my logics

Comment: @naeem007saif so asking to someonelse to do it for you, won't make you reach the goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your code you do not need to set the message to empty while you checking `ex.InnerException == null` just return the message either it is null or not.

```
    public static string GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        string message ="";

        if (ex != null)
        {            
            if (ex.InnerException == null)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
            else
            {
              return  GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException);
            }

        }

        return ""; 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You always return an *empty string* - please, note *abscence* of `ex.Message`. Something like this:

```
public static string GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(Exception ex) {
  if (null == ex)                     // no exception -
    return "";                        //   we return an empty string
  else if (null == ex.InnerException) // exception with no inner one - 
    return ex.Message;                //   time to return the message
  else                                // exception which has deeper one - 
    return GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException); // level down
}
```

Or turnary operator

```
public static string GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(Exception ex) =>
   ex == null                ? "" 
 : ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message 
 : GetFirstOccuredExceptionMessage(ex.InnerException);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static void Main()
{
  var e = new Exception("a1", new Exception("a2", new Exception("a3", new Exception("a4", new Exception("a5")))));
  var mostInner = GetMostInnerEx(e);
}

public static Exception GetMostInnerEx(Exception ex)
{
  if (ex == null) return null;
  // Just check if inner excepiton is null, if so, do recursive call to this function with inner exception
  // When inner excepiton is null, return current exception
  return ex.InnerException == null ? ex : GetMostInnerEx(ex.InnerException);
}
```